# syntactical use of comma operator in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, comma-operator

I was going through someone elses code and I wasn't able to get the syntax of following

```
c = x<0 ? x = -x,'L':'R';
```

and

```
if(x) x--,putchar(c);
```

going by the symantics, it is clear that in the first, variable c is assigned 'L' or 'R'.And in the second, both x-- and putchar() are executed. But what exactly is the role of **comma operator** here??

Comment: Really, whoever wrote this code should be LARTed. It's incredibly difficult to read -- even if you know what the `,` operator does -- and provides no performance benefit over alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what exactly is the role of comma operator here?

In this case, code obfuscation. The original developer probably thought they were being clever.

The comma operator allows you to perform multiple actions in a single statement, but you are almost always better off using 2 statements. In those cases, it expands to:

```
if( x < 0 ) {
    x = -x;
    c = 'L';
} else {
    c = 'R';
}
```

and

```
if(x) {
    x--;
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: *"In this case, code obfuscation."* Stopped here, gave +1, then finished reading.

Answer (score 5):

The comma operator evaluates both expressions, and returns the value of the last.

- The first expression does two things in one statement. If chooses 'L'
  or 'R' and also sets x to its negative if 'L' is chosen.
- The second expression (the part after the 'if') decrements x and then
  puts a character. The meaning of this is unclear without more context.

Readability in both could be improved by using separate statements rather than the comma operator. The first tries to shoehorn an `if` statement into a conditional expression. But the second is already using an `if` statement, so it's unclear why the comma operator was chosen at all.

Comment: And, in C++, the comma operator can be overloaded (as with most other operators, of course) -- so watch out for that possibility as well.

Comment: @cdhowie some programmers should be burned at the stake

Comment: @Eric No argument from me whatsoever.

Comment: in the first expression when I use ;(semicolon) in place of ,(comma), the compiler gave me an error. So, is using comma operator the only way, we could execute more than one expressions inside a ternary operator??

Comment: IOW: It chooses 'L' or 'R' and also sets x to absolute value.     A clever trick that might be useful in a macro or inline function, but unless well commented, it is certainly not easy to understand code.

Comment: @vinit - Well, the ternary could execute multiple expressions contained in a function call or larger expression. But in ternary example, x=-x is a perfectly good statement than can stand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

The role of the comma operator in that context is to allow using the conditional operator and write an assignment as part of the evaluation of one of the expressions.

In my opinion, this is just horrible style. An `if` statement would have better communicated the intent of that code, and would have hardly been less efficient.